# AWS DMS Aurora to Kinesis not replicating entire record in the JSON for DELETE operations and also stopping after running for sometime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I have set up a DMS task with Aurora Postgres RDS as the source and Kinesis Data Stream as the target. The requirement is to emit the table level events as JSON through KDS so that consuming systems can do whatever they want to do with the CDC data.

Now, there are 2 problems that keep reappearing, and neither AWS folks nor the limited available information on the internet is able to mitigate the issue.

I have tried both PGLOGICAL and TEST_DECODING plugins and neither solves the problem.

Issue 1: Ongoing replication task stopping after kicking off successfully and broadcasting the data, the error that keeps reappearing is: **Last Error An internal WAL conversational protocol error has occurred. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL**

How to fix this?

Issue 2: Insert and Update is getting all the row attributes along with the operation indicator as the following example.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 5,
    "job_code": "DE108",
    "insertdate": "2023-05-12T07:53:09.303733Z",
    "dml_operation": "INSERT",
    "target_load_time": "2023-05-12T07:53:09Z",
    "source_updated_time": "2023-05-12T07:53:09.303940000Z",
    "Operation": "I"
},
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": "2023-05-12T07:53:14.307236Z",
    "record-type": "data",
    "operation": "insert",
    "partition-key-type": "schema-table",
    "schema-name": "kinesis_replica_test",
    "table-name": "test",
    "transaction-id": 55954267
}
```

}

However, for DELETE the **job_code** attribute is missing in the JSON unlike the INSERT/UPDATE operation above. Example,

```
{
"data": {
    "id":   3,
    "dml_operation":    "DELETE",
    "target_load_time": "2023-05-12T07:22:24Z",
    "source_updated_time":  "2023-05-12T07:22:24.614659000Z"
},
"metadata": {
    "timestamp":    "2023-05-12T07:22:29.636221Z",
    "record-type":  "data",
    "operation":    "delete",
    "partition-key-type":   "schema-table",
    "schema-name":  "kinesis_replica_test",
    "table-name":   "test",
    "transaction-id":   54799561
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong or misconfiguring? Note, I have tried adding **Transformation** rules like below  that also didn't work for the DELETE:

```
{
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-id": "686281946",
  "rule-name": "686281946",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "event_test",
    "table-name": "%"
  },
  "rule-action": "add-column",
  "value": "Operation",
  "expression": "operation_indicator('D', 'U', 'I')",
  "data-type": {
    "type": "string",
    "length": 50
  }
}
```